# Take input without changing the line

Tags: python, input

```
print("Please Enter:")
x = input()
print(x)
```

In the console after "Please Enter:" is printed the line changes. I want that I should be able to provide input in the same line of "Please Enter:". Is there any method to prevent the change of line?

Comment: `>>> help(print)`, or [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: @ behzad.nouri  Thanks!! It works fine for Python 3.x. But for Python 2.x it shows some error.I tried help(print) for python 2.7.9, it gives error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `print()`, use `input()` to produce the prompt:

```
x = input("Please Enter: ")
```

From the [`input()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> `input([prompt])`
>
> If the *prompt* argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline.